# Error message "Unterminated string literal"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm using jQuery to output the results of a JSON string created by PHP from a database,

The only problem is that some of the data is on multiple lines... How would I get around this causing an unterminated string literal error in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape line endings by replacing "\n" with "\\n" and "\r" with "\\r". You will also want to escape single or double quotes, depending on which you are using to delimit the string.

Comment: I think you need to edit your answer because you obviously don't want to replace "\r" with "\r" I think.

Comment: Heh, needed to do a bit of escaping myself :)

Comment: this is an idea, however there are no \n to escape... its all basically data from a database so there are no physical line breaks in there unless i change all new lines to \\n on data entry... but how would i go about that?

Comment: Line breaks *are* those characters. If you perform a regular expression replacement or string replacement using those characters, it will work.

Comment: i'm doing a str_replace() on the post var before database insertion replacing the characters as you said above, however its still putting new lines in the database and thus the string is being put over multiple lines which in javascript is not allowed.

Comment: Not in input - escape the data on output. If it does not work, post your code so we can troubleshoot it.

Comment: What does the JSON output look like? json_encode should be properly escaping line strings.

Comment: {"title":"testing again","copy":"all\r\n\r\nadvisers\r\n\r\nat\r\nnewtown","importance":"read Now","0":"date","1":"2009-09-22 13:12:22"}

Comment: That came out without newlines being escaped. 1) did stackoverflow remove extra escapes (like my initial response)? 2) are you setting the HTTP content-type header to "text/javascript"?

Comment: no stackoverflow didn't change anything.. thats exactly how it is on my screen. and the content type is correct also.

Comment: Then json_encode does not appear to be escaping its output correctly. It could be a bug in the version you are using. Before passing it to json_encode, replace instances of "\r" and "\n" in likely strings with doubly-escaped versions.

Comment: {"title":"testing again","copy":"all\r\\n\r\\nadvisers\r\\n\r\\nat\\r\\nnewtown","importance":"read Now","0":"date","1":"2009-09-22 13:12:22"}

thats what i'm getting now by doing a preg_replace and its still coming back with the string literal unterminated... this generally happens when a string is on more than one line so it's obviously not the problem here with the line breaks

Comment: Great, i've used larryb82's preg_replace to change \r into \\n\\n that as for some reason it wasn't parsing the \r so now it works... thanks to both of you guys... Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

The following code will get rid of all \r and \n characters.

```
preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', "", $stringFromDB)
```

Comment: might be safer to replace with a space